# angular animation switch 2 varying sized div

Tags: angular, animation

I have a working angular 4 animation that has 2 varying sizes that show and hide based on a checkbox.  I can't seem to get it to collapse when the larger div is hidden. I have a plunker example here: https://plnkr.co/edit/dLCIAlWhF2JdkCCMhRTC

Below are the app, template and the animations are in their own file.

I've been using angular a while, but I'm new to angular animations.  The example is something I've pieced together from other examples.

edit:  I changed the animation a bit based on a new example.  I am now wonder if there's a way to make the footer (or anything under the animation) slide down as the large div slides down.  I would also like the footer (and anything under the large div) to slide up when the larger piece slides up and away.

app.ts

```js
//our root app component
//angular libraries
import { NgModule, Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, NgControl, Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validator, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate, keyframes, group } from '@angular/animations';
import { SlideInOutAnimation } from './animations';

@Component({
  moduleId: __moduleName,
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './template.html',

    animations: [SlideInOutAnimation],
})

export class App implements OnInit {
  name:string;

  sameAsHomeAddress: Address = new Address();
  newAddress: Address = new Address();

  sameAsAddress: boolean = true;

  animationState = 'in';
  animationStateForm = 'out';

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.name = 'Angular! Animation Test';
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  this.sameAsHomeAddress.AddressLine1 = '123 add1';
  this.sameAsHomeAddress.AddressLine2 = '';
  this.sameAsHomeAddress.City = 'city';
  this.sameAsHomeAddress.StateProvince = 'ST';
  this.sameAsHomeAddress.PostalCode = '12345';

  this.addressForm = this.fb.group({
    'fbSameAsAddress': [this.sameAsAddress],
        address: this.fb.group({
          'fbAddressLine1': [this.newAddress.AddressLine1, Validators.required],
          'fbAddressLine2': [this.newAddress.AddressLine2],
          'fbCity': [this.newAddress.City, Validators.required],
          'fbStateProvince': [this.newAddress.StateProvince, Validators.required],
          'fbPostalCode': [this.newAddress.PostalCode, Validators.required]
        })
      });

  }

toggleAnimationState() {
  this.animationState = this.animationState === 'out' ? 'in' : 'out';
  this.animationStateForm = this.animationStateForm === 'out' ? 'in' : 'out';
  }
}

export class Address {

    public AddressLine1?: string;
    public AddressLine2?: string;
    public City?: string;
    public Country?: string;
    public StateProvince?: string;
    public PostalCode?: string;
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, BrowserAnimationsModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

template.html

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="ibox">
      <div class="ibox-title">
          <h2>{{name}}</h2>
      </div>

      <div class="ibox-content ibox-content-profile">
        <div class="panel panel-default">

          <div class="panel-body">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">

                  <form novalidate [formGroup]="addressForm">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>ADDRESS</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary col-md-12">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="homeaddress" name="SameAsAddress" formControlName="fbSameAsAddress" [(ngModel)]="sameAsAddress" (click)="toggleAnimationState()">
                                <label for="homeaddress">
                                    Same As My Home Address
                                </label>
                                <div>
                                  <div class="m-l-sm address-text"  [@slideInOut]="animationState">
                                      <small>
                                          {{sameAsHomeAddress.AddressLine1}}<br>
                                          {{sameAsHomeAddress.AddressLine2}}<br>
                                          {{sameAsHomeAddress.City}}, {{sameAsHomeAddress.StateProvince}} {{sameAsHomeAddress.PostalCode}}
                                      </small>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <div id="show-hide-address" formGroupName="address"  [@slideInOut]="animationStateForm">
                          <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-xs-12">
                                  <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error': !addressForm.controls.address.controls.fbAddressLine1.valid && addressForm.controls.address.controls.fbAddressLine1.touched}">
                                      <label>ADDRESS</label>
                                      <span *ngIf="addressForm.controls.address.controls.fbAddressLine1.touched && addressForm.controls.address.controls.fbAddressLine1.errors?.required" class="text-danger"> Required</span>
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control m-b-sm" name="address1" formControlName="fbAddressLine1" [(ngModel)]="newAddress.AddressLine1" maxlength="40" />
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address2" formControlName="fbAddressLine2" [(ngModel)]="newAddress.AddressLine2" placeholder="PO Box 222" maxlength="40" />
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7">
                                  <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error': !addressForm.controls.address.controls.fbCity.valid && addressForm.controls.address.controls.fbCity.touched}">
                                      <label>CITY</label>
                                      <span *ngIf="addressForm.controls.address.controls.fbCity.touched && addressForm.controls.address.controls.fbCity.errors?.required" class="text-danger"> Required</span>
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" formControlName="fbCity" [(ngModel)]="newAddress.City" maxlength="25" />
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
                                  <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error': !addressForm.controls.address.controls.fbStateProvince.valid && addressForm.controls.address.controls.fbStateProvince.touched}">
                                      <label>STATE</label>
                                      <span *ngIf="addressForm.controls.address.controls.fbStateProvince.touched && addressForm.controls.address.controls.fbStateProvince.errors?.required" class="text-danger"> Required</span>
                                      <select class="form-control" name="states" formControlName="fbStateProvince" [(ngModel)]="newAddress.StateProvince">
                                          <option *ngFor="let x of stateList" [value]="x.StateCode">{{x.StateCode}} - {{x.Name}}</option>
                                      </select>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-xs-12">
                                  <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error': !addressForm.controls.address.controls.fbPostalCode.valid && addressForm.controls.address.controls.fbPostalCode.touched}">
                                      <label>ZIP CODE</label>
                                      <span *ngIf="addressForm.controls.address.controls.fbPostalCode.touched && addressForm.controls.address.controls.fbPostalCode.errors?.required" class="text-danger"> Required</span>
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="postalcode" formControlName="fbPostalCode" [(ngModel)]="newAddress.PostalCode" maxlength="10" />
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <!--end hide -->
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>

                </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="panel-footer">
            <h3>Some Footer</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

animations.ts

```
    import { trigger, state, style, transition,
    animate, group, query, stagger, keyframes
} from '@angular/animations';

export const SlideInOutAnimation = [
    trigger('slideInOut', [
    state('in', style({
        'height': '*', 'opacity': '1', 'overflow': 'hidden', 'visibility': 'visible'
    })),
    state('out', style({
        'height': '0px', 'opacity': '0', 'overflow': 'hidden', 'visibility': 'hidden'
    })),
    transition('in => out', [group([
        animate('.25s ease-in-out', style({
            'opacity': '0'
        })),
        animate('.6s ease-in-out', style({
            'height': '0px'
        })),
        animate('1s ease-in-out', style({
            'visibility': 'hidden'
        }))
    ]
    )]),
    transition('out => in', [group([
        animate('.25s ease-in-out', style({
            'visibility': 'visible'
        })),
        animate('.6s ease-in-out', style({
            'height': '*'
        })),
        animate('1s ease-in-out', style({
            'opacity': '1'
        }))
    ]
    )])
])
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did finally get this to work.  It would not work with the ngIf, so I added an animation state toggle method on the checkbox click and gave each div it's own animation state.

I updated the plnkr link and the code above to the working version.